# test driven development 'cannot be modified on an update' rspec wont accept the validation I've done

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

This is my first time building a ruby on rails application through test driven development.
I'm currently trying to make sure that a user_id isn't changed when an update is called. I'm still getting errors when I run rspec.

here is the test

```
it 'group_id' do
    m = create(:group_membership)
    m.should be_valid
    m.group_id = -1
    m.should have(1).errors_on(:group_id)
end
```

and here is the validation in the model that I have implemented

```
validate :validate_group_id_hasnt_changed, :on => :update

def validate_group_id_hasnt_changed
    errors.add :group_id, 'Group ID cannot be modified' if self.group_id_changed?
end
```

the test in rspec still fails even with this code, I'm wondering why? I'm pretty confident about my tests, its the actual validation I think I have wrong.

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: m.save; m.should have(1).errors_on(:group_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an issue of persistience. Running

```
m.should have(1).....
```

would re-run any validations.

The problem is else where. Check your other validations or your factory generator for ":group_membership".

Comment: thanks, found a bug in the factorygirl file for group_memberships.
I was sure the tests were written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not persisting the model; no validation will run.

Comment: my other validations work fine. the simple stuff like `validates :user_id, :presence => true`

Comment: @arg0 I don't see how; validation doesn't run when you change a persisted attribute, it runs when you validate, either manually, via a save, via a controller method that does something, etc.

Comment: sorry I'm still new to allot of these concepts, are you saying I should do what itsnikolay has suggested? and add a `m.save` in my test

Comment: @arg0 Yes; all yo've done is modified a value. That doesn't cause validation to fire. You might just be able to say that it should not be valid, too; I'm not sure. But without causing the validation flow to begin, it won't work.